# How to configure Centos 5.3 using OpenLDAP to store and serve SSH public keys?

Tags: ssh, ldap, openldap, centos5, ssh-keys

I want to be able to manage all my users logins via OpenLDAP.
I am using Centos 5.3, OpenSSH 4.3p2-42 and OpenLDAP 2.3.43.
I have installed GOsa2.

Is there a GOsa plugin to manage the SSH keys in LDAP?

I came across the openssh-lpk patch but it applies against a newer OpenSSH. I don't want to break my server. Is there a `yum` repository available with this patch applied? Do I even need it?

How can I get OpenSSH to query the LDAP server for the keys?
Can I configure PAM to do this somehow?

Advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have  struggle one this one as well for some time. Firstly check the version of openssh is >6.2 then the syntax of the sshpublickey from gosa.

I had it on Debian 7.7 then dist upgrade to Debian 8 to get the latest openSSH features.

Do

```
ldapsearch  -x '(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid='<Your user>'))' sshPublickey
```

If you have added it with gosa it will probably say something like

> sshPublicKey::c3NoLXJzYSBBQUFBQ........ bla bla

This is because it is getting hashed in someway that I haven't figured out yet but you can at this manually with creating a file called e.g sshkey.ldif
and add the following content

```
dn: cn=Jonas Pedersen,ou=people,dc=kirk,dc=local
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: ldapPublicKey
-
add: sshPublicKey
sshPublicKey: ssh-rsa <your_key> "Comment" jkp@aptproxy
```

Then modify it with ldapmodify

```
ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=kirk,dc=local -W -f sshkey.ldif
```

My entries looked like this with Gosa and with ldapmodify
[image: Gosa]
[image]

Then take a look here [ldap-ssh-key](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap)